# Date value became null while using nadateformatter in uitableview cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter, mobile-application

I am getting an array of values including date from server.  When I show date in tableview I need to change formate. so here is my array:

```
{
    amount = "-651.5700"; 
    "date_added" = "2014-04-14 03:03:10";
    description = "Order Amount Paid ";
    "transaction_id" = 795;
},  {
    amount = "-1985.0700";
    "date_added" = "2014-04-14 03:03:10";
    description = "Order Amount Paid ";
    "transaction_id" = 794;
}
```

And code I use to show date in table view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is:

```
 NSString *str=[[[ArrDashboard objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date_added"] copy];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"]; 
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];  
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; 
  NSString *strMyDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
  cell.LblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strMyDate];
```

I get many values in array but after conversion some of them values I am getting null and some are converted date string.
It would be appriciated if anyone can help.
Thank you.

Comment: For which dates do you get null? - The first date format probably has to be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" with uppercase "HH" for the 24-hour format.

Comment: Hey @MartinR ! Thank you so much. Its working fine now. after changing formate to uppercase HH. I am not getting null value now. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You should bookmark the [Date Format Patterns page](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *str=[[[ArrDashboard objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date_added"] copy]; 
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; 
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; 
    NSString *strMyDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 
    cell.LblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strMyDate];
```

Your date formate is wrong for the one that you are fetching form the response

Answer (score -1):

Alloc you dateformatter Try this code work perfect

```
    NSString *str=@"2014-04-14 03:03:10";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSString *strMyDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString *strResult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strMyDate];
```

Comment: Oh?  Try it with "2014-04-14 13:03:10".